# Steps to setup Google Ads for Android app

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, google-ads-api

Do require setup for link Google Ads, Google Playstore with Firebase. Because tracking is very important before starting any campaigns

Answer (score 0):

Basic & require steps for setup and enable Google Ads to start the campaigns

1. **Firebase link Adword & Goole Play Store**: Project Settings> Integration > Now link both accounts (You need owner access for Firebase and Playstore to get this done)
2. **Enable Firebase Events Conversation**: Some of the default events will be automatic enabled like - first_open, session_start, in_app_purchase etc. Additionally, you can mark as enable which you need to track for Ads campaign
3. Import this #2 events in Adwords account - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034306?hl=en